# How to properly use variadic functions

Tags: c

I wrote the following code:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double average(int count, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;
    double sum = 0;

    va_start(ap, count); /* Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address) */
    for (j = 0; j < count; j++) {
        sum += va_arg(ap, double); /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
    }
    va_end(ap);

    return sum / count;
}

int main(){
  int count = 3;
  double result = average(count, 10, 20, 20);
  printf("result = %f\n", result);
}
```

My intention is to compute the averages of the sum of the arguments (except the first argument which is the number of argument). But the print value is 0.00000. What is the problem of the code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't pass `double`s to the function. Try

```
  double result = average(count, 10.0, 20.0, 20.0);
```

Answer (score 5):

You are attempting to read an `int` as a `double` which will not work. `cast` and get the arg as an `int`:

```
sum += (double) va_arg (ap, int);   /* Increments ap to the next argument. */
```

**output:**

```
result = 16.666667
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I prefer to change the input of the function to double instead of changing what the function takes as input.

Comment: That's 100% OK. Whether you make the variadic `double` or `int` you just have to be consistent in the definition and use. My Answer was addressed to your **specific** question **What is the problem of the code?**